# laravel blade template printing recursive tree

Tags: php, laravel

tree.blade.php

```
<ul>

@foreach($places as $p)
    <li>
     <a href="">{{ $p->name }}</a>

    @if($p->children->count())

          @include ('tree', ['places' => $p->children]) //recursion
    @endif
    </li>
@endforeach

</ul>
```

I have 2 rows in my database, so the 2 is child to 1, the problem is that when the first tree is printed, it returns back to the second iteration, but this second iteration is the child one to the first, so it should not be printed again, it created duplication, how should I prevent this in my blade template

**updated:**

controller method:

```
public function index()
{
    $data = [];
    $data['places'] = Place::with(['children', 'parent'])->get();

    return view('places/index', $data);
}
```

Comment: Can you show your controller method?

Comment: @RossWilson question updated

Comment: How deep can the nesting go (are you setting a limit) and how many rows do you expect could eventually have in your db?

Comment: @RossWilson i have only 2 rows, there are no limits, I just want to print the one that was printed before, because is a children already of the first it is printed in a deeper loop,

Comment: Ah ok. What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson the last one 5.6

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options you have at this point.

**1) Let Eloquent do the heavy lifting**

For a small/low traffic application I would say this approach is fine but not overly efficient as it will load each relationship one by one, however, it should give you the desired results:

```
$data['places'] = Place::whereNull('parent_id')->with('children')->get();
```

Checking for the `parent_id` being `null` will get only the root elements.

**2) Build a tree**

The other option which would be a bit more efficient (DB-wise) would be to load all of the categories and build the tree in your controller:

```
$allPlaces = Place::all();

function getChildren($places, $place)
{
    $children = $places->where('parent_id', $place->id)->all()
        ->map(function ($child) use ($places) {
            return getChildren($places, $child);
        });

    $place->setRelation('children', $children);

    return $place;
}

$data['places'] = $allPlaces
    ->filter(function ($place) {
        return is_null($place->parent_id);
    })
    ->map(function ($place) use ($allPlaces) {
        return getChildren($allPlaces, $place);
    });
```

**3) Use nested sets**

It might be a bit over kill at this point but it would be worth having a look at https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Comment: I tried your second option and I get an error:

Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in

this is in the getChildren function

Comment: @Skrudox My bad, it should have been `all` not `get`.